# Implications of multiple <script> tags in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read that it is not recommended to instantiate jQuery multiple times in your HTML. This makes perfect sense to me, but:
Isn't Javascript single-threaded anyway? And leaving jQuery behind, how does the browser execute these multiple script tags? In parallel or one after another?

Thanks, Philip

Comment: "I have read that it is not recommended to instantiate jQuery multiple times in your HTML": do you have a link about that?

Comment: No sorry, maybe I also got something wrong or missed a detail. Actually jQuery is stateless, but the Plugins can (and must in some cases) be instantiated multiple times.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Simple answer:**

In a simple scenario (tags are part of original HTML text), the browser definitely executes them one after another.

**Detailed discussion with different caveats**

JavaScript isn't necessarily single-threaded (it depends on the implementation of your JavaScript engine, e.g. see [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers)).

BUT, the individual `<script>` tags are executed sequentially.

For reference, please see `JavaScript: The Definitive Guide`. Quoting Chapter "12.3. Execution of JavaScript Programs":

> JavaScript statements that appear between  and  tags are executed in order of appearance; when more than one script appears in a file, the scripts are executed in the order in which they appear. If a script calls document.write( ), any text passed to that method is inserted into the document immediately after the closing  tag and is parsed by the HTML parser when the script finishes running. The same rules apply to scripts included from separate files with the src attribute.

---

Please note that the above is only true of "straight up" execution of code in tags. The order can, however, be affected by:

- `setTimeout()` calls (duh)
- [defer attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)
- Dynamic attachement of the `<script>` tags - see the last section of this answer.

---

As a **caveat**, please note that JavaScript code loaded externally via `<script src="xxxx" />` would still be executed sequentially, BUT, it is quite possible that the browser would **DOWNLOAD** the code in parallel - depends on browser implementation (but still schedule the execution of downloaded code snippets in correct order).

This caveat is important in case you want to have some weird hack whereas the URL for the JavaScript source is actually a CGI script which does something and you try to depend on the correct order of downloads for the logic in the script.

Again, it would have no bearing on your browser JS engine's execution order of those script pieces.

---

However, a far more **important caveat** is that if you actually attach the `<script>` tags with external sources dynamically (e.g. via `appendChild()` call), according to [this SO post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2006/12/22/loading-javascript-files-in-parallel.aspx), as well as the [MSDN blog the post was based on](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2006/12/22/loading-javascript-files-in-parallel.aspx), non-IE browsers **do NOT guarantee the order of execution!** It will depend on which tag's code finished downloading first!

Comment: Thank you for this encyclopedic answer!

Comment: By the way, this seems to be a point where IE is ahead of the competition ;)

Comment: @DVK :Does that mean in <script type="text/javascript"> if we are including couple of script and each are doing  AJAX and other function calls.Will the 1st in sequence will complete all the execution? and it move to the next script? or it is just it will decide the starting order not the finishing order?

Comment: @DVK: also can you provide your views on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254196/disable-tabs-and-submit-button-on-form-until-all-the-script-executes

Answer (score 7):

The fewer calls you make that instantiate a jQuery object, the less overhead you have -- but even if you are designing for old browsers running on 2nd generation hardware be wary of micro-optimizations.  Profile your application and fix the parts that *actually* are the bottlenecks.

As for the way browsers handle multiple script tags -- it varies from browser to browser, from version to version, and sometimes even from operating system to operating system.  All browsers execute each script tag in document order:

```
<script src="scripts/some_script.js"></script> <!-- Executed 1st -->
<script src="scripts/some_other_script.js"></script> <!-- Executed 2nd -->
<script>
// Some JavaScript
</script> <!-- Executed 3rd -->
<script>
// Some More JavaScript
</script> <!-- Executed 4th -->
```

However, other behaviors are not defined and there is variation.  For example, Opera (at least on Windows XP for version 10.6) ran each script tag in its own context -- so local variables in the 3rd script block would be out of scope if referred to in the 4th script block.

```
<script>
var i = 42;
</script>
<script>
alert(i);
// Alerts "undefined" in Opera, but 42 in Firefox.
</script>
```

Comment: I think it's important to note that if we are talking about ECMA compliant browsers, then there is no difference between browser or OS - - there is just one Execution Context in an ECMA implementation.  The version of Opera that you cite must not be ECMA compliant.

Comment: Can you comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254196/disable-tabs-and-submit-button-on-form-until-all-the-script-executes

Answer (score 2):

The browser executes JavaScript sequentially (the same is true for jQuery since jQuery is just JavaScript).

As for having multiple script tags in HTML, there's no reason why this would be a problem. As Nabab asked, I would be interested in seeing your source for that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the browser compile all the javascript anyway into one "file" during processing. For example, if you had multiple $(document).ready() calls across multiple files, when the browser pre-processes the page, it essentially condenses everything down for execution - and runs it sequentially in the order it was 'seen'.

Comment: I would suggest that putting multiple event handlers for `$(document).ready(){});` or the recommended form `$(function(){});` would be a poor practice to use, strive to only have this event handler once on a page

Answer (score -3):

Yes, we can write any number of  tags inside  tag. And browser access them in sequential order.

```
 <html>
   <body>

    <!-- here your code-->

      <script></script>
      <script></script>
      <script></script>
              .
              .
              .
      <script></script>

    </body>
</html>
```