# may i use two times in javascript in same page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to post form value using javascript. And some functions in individual textbox and selection option. so may i invoke two times in javascript or ajax, jquery. thanks in advance.

```
<script>
//script function
</script>
<input type="text" name="name">
<script>
//another script function
</script>
```

Comment: My suggestion is keep javascript content in separate .js file and include it.Add all the js stuff in that file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implications of multiple <script> tags in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659409/implications-of-multiple-script-tags-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<script>` in you document as many times you want.
But don't do it in a **render-blocking** way (all around your HTML): instead place your `<script>` tags before the closing `</body>` tag.
Additionally you might want to minify and join all your scripts at build time into a single JS file.