# Why won't my two separate scripts run in serial in my html document?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn JavaScript.  I'm very new (started this week).  I'm following the exercises available at [javascript.info](https://javascript.info).

This is the html code I'm opening in firefox:

```html
<p>First, we have a prompt that incorrectly concatenates input strings.</p>
<script>
  let a = prompt("First number?", 1);
  let b = prompt("Second number?", 2);

  alert(a + b); // 12
</script>
<p>Now we correctly cast to integer, and then do addition.</p>
<script>
  let a = prompt("First number?", 1);
  let b = prompt("Second number?", 2);

  a = Number(a);
  b = Number(b);

  alert(a + b); // 3
</script>
<p>Well, that's all folks!</p>
```

For some reason, the first script will run, but the second won't.  I've checked around (https://www.quora.com/Can-I-call-two-JavaScript-files-in-one-HTML-file and [Implications of multiple <script> tags in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659409/implications-of-multiple-script-tags-in-html)) and it seems like they should just run in sequence.

Comment: You already declared the variable. Consider checking the browser console for errors before posting

Comment: you could warp your code in a anonymous function. !function() { //your code here }(). This will declare the variables in function scope and solve your problem. The "!" before the functions will trigger it's execution.